# WIFI speed is too slow in ubuntu gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, gnome

I am running ubuntu gnome dual booted with windows 10.
In windows I can stream 1440p videos on YouTube without buffering, In ubuntu the signal strength is too low and even at a close distance 720p video still buffers.

result for lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
08:00.0     

Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE 
PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]

DeviceName: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 Combo Adapter

Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
[103c:804c]

Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Kernel modules: rtl8723be  
09:00.0     Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: And what is the kernel version `uname -a`?